# add ffmpeg.exe, ffprobe.exe, D3DCompiler_43.dll to exe file by using pyinstaller

Tags: ffmpeg, pyinstaller

Execution Environment : Windows10, Anaconda, Python3.6

My program use  ffmpeg.exe, ffprobe.exe, D3DCompiler_43.dll in execution.

I must make .exe file including them all.

I try

`pyinstaller setup.spec`

It completed successfully. 
But, .exe file doesn't work properly.

[setup.spec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iu9t5.jpg)
[outcome of exe file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYmmJ.jpg)